# Upload to AWS S3 'folder' inside bucket with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Apologies, I'm not an AWS user. I need to upload a file to a 'folder' in an existing bucket within AWS S3. I understand that there is no concept of 'folders' within S3, so how I could specify the 'folder' it needs to go to?

My uploaded image needs to follow an existing structure of

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/my.bucket.name/newfolder/test_image.png
```

The code I have below works, but it puts the image into the root bucket, whereas I need to put it into a new folder ($newfolder).

Does anyone know where in the below code I could specify the $newfolder to achieve this?

Thank you.

```
<?php
$newfolder = "newfolder";
$bucket = 'my.bucket.name';
require_once('S3.php');

$awsAccessKey = 'MyAccessKey';
$awsSecretKey = 'MySecretKey';

$s3 = new S3($awsAccessKey, $awsSecretKey);
$s3->putBucket($bucket, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

$actual_image_name = 'test_image.png';

if($s3->putObjectFile('/var/www/html/test/image.png', $bucket , $actual_image_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) )
    {
    $image='http://'.$bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$actual_image_name;
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'error uploading to S3 Amazon';
    }  
?>
```

Comment: Hi @omega, from where I can get S3.php file to run this script? are you using any aws library for uploading on AWS S3 Bucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$actual_image_name = 'newfolder/test_image.png';
```

S3 calls this the *key* inside the *bucket*. The key can contain slashes, which would be treated as folders when viewed using an appropriate client. But the concept of "folders" doesn't matter much when dealing with the S3 API nor URLs, so it's just "keys" with slashes in them.

Comment: That simple? I'm sure I should have tried that :-/ Many thanks sir! Will mark as answer.